# Subsites Not Listed Under Site Collections

Tags: search, office-365, site-collection, sub-site

The organization has many team sites and sub-sites that are not listed in the Site Collections part of the SharePoint Admin menu.  Have the sites been created incorrectly?  I have tried to search for the sites that are not present, and Search doesn't find them that way either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Admin center, we can only see the Site collections list but Sub-Sites are part of Site collection and live within that site collection.

I am sure you are seeing something like this (image from my test tenant)
[image]

you will see only site collections, but when you click any of the site collection url and get the properties of that site collections then you will see the number of subsites in that site collection.

[image]

Comment: Indeed.  That is exactly what I see, although it has now raised a new problem.  I have created 2 sub-sites.  I know of 1 that already existed before I became an admin, and one is apparently hidden from my view still.  This is more of a security issue than anything else.

Follow-up question:
How do I see every site our company has created?

Comment: can you open a new questions for that, i think you can get it via powershell easily. Its hard for other to respond in the comments....I appreciate your time.

Comment: I will.  Unfortunately I can only ask a question one time every 40 minutes.  Which I'm sure is a way to control the input into the site and prevent bots or something more nefarious.

However!  The last time I posted that question it was deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Sub-Sites are not site collections.

They wont be listed there since they are only a "site"

Anything directly under /sites/ is a site collection. Also the root sites, search and the mysitehost are Sitecollection.

A Sitecollection can have a quota assigned and is not inheriting security from its parent (Its a security boundary) , since it has none.

Comment: Then why are other sites listed here.  We have two listed under Site Collections.  All of the other ones that exist in the company are not listed.  What would make those two different?

Comment: Anything directly under /sites/ is a Sitecollection. Also the root sites, search and the mysitehost are Sitecollection. A Sitecollection can have a quota assigned and is not inheriting security from its parent, since it has none